# Are phrases "an intelligent man" and "a smart person" different? Which ones is better to use for a personal characteristic?

Tags: phrase-choice

There are two different phrases:

- intelligent man
- smart person

Which one should I use for a personal characteristic?

Comment: a person is not necessarily a man. Smart means intelligent in AmE. In BrE, smart means well dressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all persons are men.  In fact most persons are not men.

Smart can mean either "well dressed" or "intelligent" so, you might describe a foolish woman in a tailored suit "a smart person", but she is not "an intelligent man"